# Software to "control" a video show

Tags: video, software-recommendation, software

I'm working on a magicians show.

They need some videos to be played during it, but the timings of their work could vary.

So I was wondering if I could find some kind of software that could be used to control how videos do play, and that they could control with a keyboard.
It would be quite simple, they idea is to have some videos that would loop, waiting for a "user" action.

Eg.

- video A >>>
- video B - video loop - when key is pressed, plays until its end then goes to...
- video C>>>
- video B - video loop - when key is pressed, plays until its end then goes to...
- video D
- etc.

I used to do this with Flash back in the days.
Maybe is there a better tool to achieve this now, and which would handle videos in a better way (Flash was bad for videos !)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For live event video display, I would search for "VJ software."  Because (a) I'm a video editor who uses DaVinci Resolve in his daily life and (b) I sometimes make typos when performing internet searches, I've stumbled across a piece of software called "Resolume," which appears to be highly regarded in this space, although I cannot comment on its quality or efficacy.  https://resolume.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with Fast Video Cataloger. [videocataloger.com](https://videocataloger.com)
I would test using playlists and Custom Actions. I am not sure if it covers what you need but can be worth a test.
Create a catalog with your videos. Tag these with keywords.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS check out VDMX.
You could also try processing.org and create something that can do exactly what you need.